# jQuery Autosuggest

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, autosuggest

I am pretty new to jQuery, so I need some help here:
I just started using [jQuery Autosuggest Plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin), because I would really help my site. I downloaded all of the files, linked them to my site, and used this, to set an input as autosuggest:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#postna").autoSuggest("get.php");
})
</script>
```

Now this part works fine, it changes the style of my input box. And for get.php file, I pretty much copied it from the plugin site, but I changed it, so it would serve me better:

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/mysql.class.php';

$input = $_GET['q'];
$data = array();

$qu = new MySQL();
$qu->rQuery("SELECT id,name FROM cities WHERE name LIKE '$input%'");
$data = $qu->getRows();
foreach($data as $a){
    $json = array();
    $json['value'] = $a['id'];
    $json['name'] = $a['name'];
    $data[] = $json;
}
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

The problem now is, that when I input my text it returns "No results found", but if I go to /get.php?q=velenje (velenje is a name of a city), it echoes this:

```
{"id":"681","name":"Velenje"}
```

Any suggestion on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you fire up Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and post what is sent and received to/from the server?

Comment: what is the output of get.php if you plug in the address manually?

Comment: @Brad, the GET seems to be correct: `GET /get.php?q=velenje HTTP/1.1`; thanks for the program, I've been looking for something a bit less complicated than WireShark.
@Tim, it echoes `{"id":"681","name":"Velenje"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pulling the results of your MySQL query into an array `$data` and then proceeding to edit that array in a loop.  Try this:

```
$data = array();
$qu = new MySQL();
$qu->rQuery("SELECT id,name FROM cities WHERE name LIKE '$input%'");
$rows = $qu->getRows();
foreach($rows as $a){
    $json = array();
    $json['value'] = $a['id'];
    $json['name'] = $a['name'];
    $data[] = $json;
}    
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($data);
```

**EDIT**: I forgot to note that you don't appear to be sanitizing your inputs...  [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) shows us why we shouldn't do that.

Comment: This doesn't work either. Also, it's only a test script, to actually get the thing working. I plan on fixing the security issues later.

Comment: @Grega - If you're using Chrome, open up the developer tools and see what is actually being loaded.  You can also see if there are any javascript errors being thrown.  Firefox has something similar but you may need to download an extension.

Comment: I have already checked that, all required scripts are being loaded, and there are no errors to be seen.

Comment: From the "Network" tab, are you able to see the "get.php" file and observe its contents?

Comment: Yes, but even though I have enteret a city into the input, I see all the cities like this: `0: {value:452, name:Ljubljana}`. Also, there is a lot of requests for search.php (the file I'm in). Is that wrong?

Comment: Hmmm - I'm not sure why, but it looks like json_encode is returning an  object rather than an array.  The return value should look like `[{value:452,name:Ljubljana},...]` rather than `{0:{value:452,name:Ljubljana}}`.

Comment: Yes, I was editing get.php and forgot to set $input to $_GET['q'];
It now returns this: `[{"value":"681","name":"Velenje"}]`, or more results, if I haven't finished typing it. But still doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Hmmm, if the javascript is being triggered, data is pulled in, and there are no errors, I'm out of ideas...sorry

Comment: Well, you've helped out a lot. I'll see if I can fix it, or I'll use something else...

Comment: Not sure if it interests you, but I finally fixed it! Apparenlty, I had to add which objects I want to display! `searchObjProps:"name", selectedItemProp:"name"`

Answer (score 0):

Use in the client side the full path to your script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#postna").autoSuggest("http://yoursite.com/get.php");
})
</script>
```